# Server and client do not wait for their buffer to be filled

Tags: c, sockets

I am building a client/server application in C. I am pretty inexperienced on the matter so what I am trying to do is pretty basic. Unfortunately I cannot divulge lots of code, except maybe for a few lines, but I hope you are able to help me anyway.

I have drawn a chart that explains what my app is supposed to do. I have two executables: the server and the client, of course.

[image: Client/Server flow.]

At first the server boots and calls `get_request()` and waits for the client.

The user interacts with the client and eventually triggers `make_a_request()` passing `REQ_TOKEN` a token with fixed length, which specifies the kind of request it wants to perform. The client invokes the `write()` system call handing over the token to the server.

```
if (write(skt, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) < 0)
    {    
        free(buffer);
        return WRITE_ERROR;
    }
```

The server was waiting on `read()` so it actually reads the token, calls the function that is supposed to handle the request and `ANS_TOKEN`, a response token, is generated. The response now *surprise, surprise* goes in the other direction. The server gets to `write()` and the client gets to `read()`.

```
token = (char *) calloc (BLEN, sizeof(char));

if ((read_bytes = read(user->skt, token, BLEN)) < 0)
{
    free(token);

    if (read_bytes <= 0)
    {
        return READ_ERR;
    }
}
```

The first time around everything goes fine. When the cycles starts again the server doesn't wait on `read()` and it goes on with an empty buffer with no token to work with and the client does the same thing on the other side.

My first attempt to get over this issue was to use a `while` and check for `read_bytes` to reach the fixed length of the token.

```
while ((rbytes = read(skt, token, BLEN)) < BELN)
    {
        if (rbytes < 0)
        {
            free(token);
            return READ_ERR;
        }
    }
```

But during execution the application crashes and I get this error:

```
*** Error in `./server': double free or 
corruption (fasttop): 0x00007fc588000a30 ***
```

My second attempty was to use `recv()`in place of `read()` didn't work so well: as client quits, the server hangs waiting for something to be in the buffer and gets stuck.

How do I prevent client and server to procede on empty buffer and make them wait for the other to write something on the socket? Why do client and server wait for their first interactions but not for the subsequent ones?

Comment: In the client-send code, either `sizeof(buffer)` or `free(buffer)` is wrong. Without seeing *real* code i cannot say which. If `buffer` is a *pointer* to dynamic memory (as suggested by the `free` call), the former is wrong. If it is a fixed native array (as suggested by the `sizeof` operator), the latter is wrong.

Comment: If there's a double free, there's something else going on that we can't see.  You'll need to trace through your logic to see where that might be happening.  It's also best to use `recv` and `send` on sockets instead of `read` and `write` as those functions are specifically for sockets.  As for the hangup you got, you should either enable non-blocking sockets or use `select` or `poll` to allow you to specify a maximum wait time.

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong `read(fd, buff, size)` and `write(fd,buf,size)` can return anything between -1 and size (inclusive). So, partial reads are possible. Also: a return value of -1 is not an error, first inspect errno (it could be EAGAIN, etc)

Comment: An error I often do is to forget to reset file desciptors using FD_SET if you are using select

Comment: regarding this line: 'if (read_bytes <= 0)' ==0 is not an error, it just means there were no bytes to read.    Strongly suggest using 'select()', perhaps with a timeout, to wait for data to be available before trying to read().  It is often true that not all bytes are available when the read() is performed.  Therefore, have to track number of bytes read and accumulate the bytes in the input buffer while keep repeating the select/read loop until enough bytes are read.